# Bash - Iterate through directory and run command on each *.py file, specifying 'yes' to prompts

Tags: bash, recursion, directory

I'm trying to write a bash script to iterate through a directory and run a command on every .py file to upload each to a different location based on its filename.
[EDIT] - in the path/to/upload/$f, the $f needs to be the name of the file (without the extension)

I'm sure I'm miles off but might it look something like this:

```
cd /home/user/stuff

for f in $(find . -name '*.py') 
do yes yes | [command] path/to/upload/$f 
done
```

except here the whole path gets assigned to $f

the directory looks like:

```
├── zero
│   ├── ein
│   │   └── ein.py
├── one
│   ├── ban
│   │   └── ban.py
│   ├── deep
│   │   └── deep.py
```

etc...

So the first iteration would go [command] path/to/upload/ein

Comment: Paste your code into https://shellcheck.net for checking.

Comment: So I probably should have specified, in the path/to/upload/$f, the $f needs to be the name of the file (without the extension). I have got slightly closer (I think) with this:


`for f in $(find . -name '*.py')
do yes yes | [command] path/to/file/$f
done`

only now the whole path gets assigned to $f, not just the filename

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) or later then you can use:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob globstar nullglob
for f in **/*.py; do
    file=${f##*/}
    yes yes | [command] "path/to/upload/${file%.py}"
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` shows such files by default.
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- `${f##*/}` expands to the value of `$f` with everything up to and including the last `/` character removed.  `${file%.py}` expands to the value of `$file` with a trailing `.py` removed.
  See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

If you are stuck with an older version of Bash (e.g. on macOS) then another option is:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

find . -name '*.py' -print0 \
    |   while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
            file=${f##*/}
            yes yes | [command] "path/to/upload/${file%.py}"
        done
```

- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' ...`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for an explanation of why commonly-seen shell code for processing the output of `find` is broken.

Comment: Great answer. It still fails unfortunately, as the path is now `path/to/upload/file.py`, but needs to be `path/to/upload/file`, i.e. the string manipulation needs to remove the .py file extension

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.py')
```

with

```
for f in $(find . | sort -r | grep "/${input}" | grep '.py$' )
```

This way, you will iterate on all python under **${input}**.

I like to use "**sort -r**" as a visual prompt that I am working down to the start of the list. :-)

Comment: Hmm...that seems to do the same thing as my code at the top? i.e. the whole path gets copied into $f.

I need it so that either the file name without extension, or the file's current directory (both are named the same) are assigned to $f.

Comment: They are not. The grep for ${input} will restrict the scope of the reported items.  If value has "ein", only one reported.  If value has "one", you will get two items reported.  If value is parent of "ein" and "one", then you will get them all.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).